# getting post feeling states ( facebook graph-api )

Tags: facebook-graph-api

Is it possible to get facebook post's feeling states using graph api ? I didn't find any docs on this . Let me know if there is any way to get it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No . there is no way to get it using facebook graph api.